# How to bind a float value in a sqlite3 database?

Tags: c, sqlite, input

I need to insert a float value that I get from the user to the sqlite3 database. For this, I am using **sqlite3_bind_double()** function.
The problem is that even if I enter a value of 23.3 in the database I still get a long double as 23.3999615.
How can I limit the number to only have two decimals to be stored in the database?

Comment: `long` and `long double` are _binary_ floating point types.  "limit the number to only have two _decimals_" is not a property of those types.

Comment: Is that truly 23.3 and not 23.4 in the example that made 23.3999615?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I understand, but can't find any other function for particularly float binding

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica as far as I remember it was 23.3, I didn't save the input anywhere so might be mistaken

Comment: The closest ieee754 double to 23.4 is 23.3999996185302734375, which is what sqlite would store internally. So if you meant 23.4 and not 23.3, that result makes sense. See [Is Floating Point Math Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @Shawn yes, but it's not the point of my question...
I want to store number with two decimals only, but couldn't find any other way rather than using bind_double

Comment: Just round it to the desired precision when formatting as a string for display?